# Boost - Ignore url variables but still cache the page

Tags: uri, caching

It seems like I'm not the only one with this problem but none of the other issues presented a clear solution.

I have a url variable called "?slide=X" which is only controlling which slide opens on the javascript slideshow when the page loads. Obviously I don't need 10 different Boost caches for each of the slides since they're all loading the same html.

All the .htaccess rules above don't really do it for me. Anybody had any luck on this?

examples.com/node/10?slide=3 needs to call the cache/normal/examplecom/node/10_.html file instead the cache/normal/examplecom/node/10_slide=3.html

Is this at all possible?

It would be great to have a general option on the settings page to ignore all url parameters or maybe ignore specific ones but still cache the pages. I think boos for D6 had this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just saw you in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2042909) :D

have you tried:

2 options to solve this. Create a rewrite rule at the server level to strip userID=1234 or in setting.php strip it out & use hook_boot to add it back in.

> A more interesting solution proposed in [this thread](http://groups.drupal.org/node/227043) by mikeytown
>   (maintainer of several high performance Drupal modules like Boost and
>   Advagg), is to remove specific query parameter at the server level or
>   in settings.php, thereby tricking Drupal into getting and setting the
>   page cache using a cleaner URL string.  This will almost certainly
>   have unintended consequences, however, and should be implemented with
>   extreme caution.

Found here: http://www.asmallwebfirm.net/blogs/2012/07/page-cache-vs-landing-page-performance

Comment: adding a rewrite rule on the .htaccess seems like the right way to do it but I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: have you tried the -s option from the drupal issue ?, like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s`

Comment: otherwise try to do it in settings.php, see the example here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102571/caching-pages-with-boost-based-on-a-cookie-value

Answer (score 0):

As per [Caching pages with boost based on a cookie value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102571/caching-pages-with-boost-based-on-a-cookie-value) resolved this by adding this to the end of my setting.php page:

```
//check if url has parameters
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?') == true) {
    //clean all parameters   
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');
}
```

Adding more php logic to ignore specific parameters should not be hard but since my website uses only one I choose to remove it all.

Answer (score 0):

What if the parameter is required for rendering the page, but not for caching? What about removing it from the cache key?